# Google Maps app crashes on open for iPad

Tags: ipad, google-maps

I'm traveling now and relying heavily on Google Maps on my iPad. with no warning, the app now crashes instantly when I click on it. no warning at all. I tap the icon, the default screen comes up, a second later the app closes.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? More imporrtantly, has anyone found a solution?

I tried restarting my iPad, as well as a hard reset. I do not have my laptop so I cannot sync. Since the app is one of the few default apps, I cannot delete and re-download it. I'm really at a loss here, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a downloaded app does two things:

1. Jettisons the data (like a reset for that app)
2. Allows for a clean copy of the app to be downloaded again

You could restore the entire device and test maps before restring your backup or you could back it up and erase all content and settings and then test.

Flip a coin if one of those two options does not seem better to you and feel free to ask a follow on question if you find some more details to add to the question and don't want to edit them into the existing question.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to say "Have you tried turning it on and off again" ;)

As an alternative to what you're experiencing whilst in your situation have you tried just using Safari and browsing to http://maps.google.com? Failing that you could download the [National Geographic Map app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-world-by-national-geographic/id454811793?mt=8). This uses some older-style-maps and if you zoom in far enough it revents to Bing Maps. I don't know why they didn't go for Google maps, probably a licensing thing as their app is a tidy $3.99.

The only real answer I can give you is update your iPad. Just think in a few months, with you'll be able to run updates without the need for a computer or iTunes.